# PHPExcel not working in Linux, have tried everything

Tags: php, linux, phpexcel

My application which makes use of PHPExcel to read a `.xlsx` file and it will not seem to work no matter what I try. It tests perfectly fine in windows but won't work in Linux.

The extensions for php are enabled, there isn't a problem with case-sensitivity of loaded classes, the classes are definitely being loaded (checked with `get_included_files) and the database connection functions are all working, I can issue an SQL command and get a table back.

This is the chunk of code which uses PHPExcel:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
  if(check_file($_FILES['file'])){

    //set the excel version needed
    $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';

    //set variable with path of file, set the sheet name we want
    $inputFileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $sheetname = 'KSAs';

    echo $inputFileName . "</br>";
    echo $sheetname . "</br>";

    //create an object reader, pass in the file type, load the file
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);

    //load the file into the reader object
    $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);


    $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

    foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
        $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
        $objWriter->save($loadedSheetName.'.csv');
    }

    echo $loadedSheetNames;
```

The very last statement echo $loadedSheetNames never executes. I am not sure what the problem could possibly be.

EDIT:

On user Raptors advice I started doing some debugging. After learning about how to properly use `var_dump` I printed out the errors. The problem is definitely in the creation of the `$objReader` class as the `var_dump` reads out:

```
object(PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007)#1 (6) {
  ["_referenceHelper":"PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007":private]=>
  object(PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper)#3 (0) {
  }
  ["_readDataOnly":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_includeCharts":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_loadSheetsOnly":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_readFilter":protected]=>
  object(PHPExcel_Reader_DefaultReadFilter)#2 (0) {
  }
  ["_fileHandle":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

The $objReader class prints out a huge result. I'm not really sure how to read the data so I think I will have to figure that out. I don't have much knowledge or experience with debugging so I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: You show no debug effort. Did you `var_dump()` the `$objWriter`, `$loadedSheetNames` and `$objPHPExcelReader` ? and what is `check_file()` ?

Comment: are you getting any error messages? check your web server log files.

Comment: `check_file` is used to make sure the file goes through okay. I don't think it causing this problem because I tried removing it from the function and it had no effect. It doesn't do much anyway. I have little experience with debugging so that's why I don't have much to show on that front.